# Field Forms dinâmicos em Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Para o meu projeto de TCC, tenho a seguinte especificação:

Um usuário, para cadastrar um item de produção, precisa informar todos os seus ingredientes. Para facilitar a interação, pensei de, listar todos os ingredientes cadastrados em checkboxes. Quando o usuário clicar em um certo link, uma função JavaScript fará a contagem dos checkboxes marcados, e daí criará em uma div os campos de texto correspondentes a cada ingrediente para que o usuário possa inserir a quantidade de cada um.Como podem acontecer marcações acidentais, na div com os inputs, ainda deverá ser possível que o usuário exclua os campos indesejados clicando em um link.

A minha dúvida é quanto ao back-end. Como fica pra eu salvar isso no banco de dados? Como vou capturar as quantidades de cada campo se eles não estão previamente criados no arquivo .html.erb?

Comment: Olá, você está usando a versão 4.1? Posta o seu código por favor! :D Valeu!

Comment: Oii @BrunoCasali
Eu ainda não comecei a implementar. 
Estou pesquisando a melhor abordagem, e se isso é possível antes de iniciar. Quanto à sua primeira pergunta, sim, estou usando a 4.1.

Comment: Cara estou começando com rails também, ainda não tive que fazer esse tipo de formulário, apenas tive umas desavenças com formulários de mais de um modelo.
Mas encontrei alguns links que acho que podem te ajudar,
[comp-groups](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.ruby/non-ajax-dynamic-form-in-rails/744332), [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670975/dynamic-fields-with-rails-3), procurei por 'dynamic forms in rails 4' :D

Answer (score 1):

O Rails vai receber o valor qualquer elemento que:

1. esteja dentro do form
2. tenha a propriedade name preenchida, mesmo que criado dinamicamente.

Como vc está usando 4.1, o strong parameters vai te obrigar a liberar os nomes de parametros válidos, tenha isso em conta.